# ASP.NET Server Controls and <%$ %> params like ConnectionStrings

Tags: .net, asp.net, session-variables, servercontrols

Is there a complete list of the objects you can tap into with <%$ %> tags in ASP.NET

I know you can do things like <%$ ConnectionStrings:northwind %> in the ConnectionString attribute of the `<asp:SqlDataSource>` tag.

Can you also do this with Cookies and Session? Is there a <%$ %> reference page out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are called [ASP.NET Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx). `AppSettings`, `ConnectionStrings`, and `Resources` are the default providers made available with ASP.NET, but one can write a custom ASP.NET Expressions provider for just about anything.

The ones you're looking for (Cookies and Session) have been written and made available [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/04/useful-expression-builders.aspx).

Comment: CodeExpressionBuilder is my favorite. You can see how it was built at http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

Comment: I ended up setting the connection in the code behind based off a Session variable. Within that .zip file there seemed to be a missing base class. It was the base class that all the "Editors" inherit from.